# Prove: $X_{n}\rightarrow a\iff$ For Every Neighbourhood $U$ Of $a$ $x_{n}\in U$

Tags: proof-verification, metric-spaces

> Prove: $X_{n}\Rightarrow a\iff$ for every neighbourhood $U$ of $a$ there is $N$ s.t for all $N\leq n, $ $x_{n}\in U$

$(\Rightarrow):$ $X_{n}\rightarrow a$ by definition for every $\epsilon>0$ there is $N\leq n$ s.t $d(x_{n},a)<\epsilon$

Which means that for some $n$'s $x_n\in B(a,\epsilon)$ and this is true for every $\epsilon$ and some $n$.

$(\Leftarrow):$ $U$ is a neighborhood of $a$ and for some $n$ $x_n\in U$ so there for every $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ there is $N\leq n$ s.t $x_n\in B(a,\frac{\epsilon}{2})\subseteq U$ which means that $d(x_n,a)<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ which means that $x_n\rightarrow a$

Is this a valid proof?

Comment: I think for $\Leftarrow$ you can just say that $B(a,\epsilon)$ is a neighbourhood of $a$

Comment: what does "$X_{n}\Rightarrow a$" mean?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown converges, I change the arrow type

Comment: In the proof of $\implies$ you actually need to end up in the thesis of the implication. In particular that there is $N$ such that for all $n>N$ $x_n\in B(a,\epsilon)$, as opposed to there is $n$ ... The latter is a weaker assertion. Likewise in $\Leftarrow$.

Comment: At the place where you write "proof" and in heading ..still you used same sign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claim: The sequence $x_n \rightarrow a$ if and only if for every (open) neighborhood $U$ of $a$, there is an $N$ such that for all $n \ge N$, $x_n \in U$.

Note: The definition you are using is, that $x_n \rightarrow a$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $N$ such that $d(x_n,a) < \epsilon$ ***for all*** $n \ge N$.

Proof:

$(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose that $x_n \rightarrow a$.

- Now consider any arbitrary open neighborhood $U$ around $a$. Since $U$ is open, there exists some $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B(a,\epsilon) \subset U$. Note I am using your notation that $B(a,\epsilon)$ is simply the open ball of radius $\epsilon$ around $a$.
- Since $x_n \rightarrow$ by hypothesis, there is an $N$ such that $x_n \in B(a,\epsilon)$ for all $n \ge N$.
- Since $B(a,\epsilon) \subset U$, we also have $x_n \in U$ for all $n \ge N$.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Suppose that for every open neighborhood $U$ of $a$, there is an $N$ such that for all $n \ge N$, $x_n \in U$.

- Fix an arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$. Clearly, $B(a, \epsilon)$ is an open neighborhood of $a$. Therefore by hypothesis, there exists an $N$ such that for all $n \ge N$, $x_n \in U$.
- By definition of $B(a, \epsilon)$, this means that for all $n \ge N$, we have $d(x_n,a) < \epsilon$. $\square$